# Negative months as difference between two dates

Tags: r, zoo, as.date

I am aware that there are some posts similar to this here on stackoverflow. But they did not directly address my issue. Here is my issue:

I have a variable called earliest_cr_line which contains dates as Jan-01. This is a string variable. I need to create a variable called "test" which should contain the difference between earliest_cr_line and Dec-2007 in months. To this end, I ran the following codes:

```
library(zoo)
loan_data$earliest_cr_line_date <- as.yearmon(loan_data$earliest_cr_line, "%b-%y")
ref_date <- as.yearmon("Dec-07", "%b-%y")
loan_data$test <- round((as.Date(ref_date) - 
as.Date(loan_data$earliest_cr_line_date))/(365.25/12))
```

However, the newly created variable test contains many negative numbers as well.  I figured out that when converting earliest_cr_line from string to yearmon, R misinterpreted years which were before 1970. For example, yearmon converted Jan-60 into Nov 2060 instead of Nov 1960. That's what is causing the negative output. Any idea how I should approach this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Date`'s integer is a day, making day-to-month determination inconsistent. `yearmon`'s integer is a year, which makes a month just `1/12`, a bit simpler to deal with. If you start with `zoo`'s yearmon object, then I suggest you stick with it instead of trying convert to/from R's `Date` object.

Handling wrong years is an annoying Y2K problem ... while this below will generally work (*assuming that everything you're looking at is in the past*), I urge you to fix this problem at the source. (I am astounded that something somewhere still thinks that 2-digit years is acceptable. *shrug*)

```r
vec <- c("Nov-60","Nov-70","Nov-71","Jan-01","Mar-05","Dec-07")
(out <- zoo::as.yearmon(vec, format="%b-%y"))
# [1] "Nov 2060" "Nov 1970" "Nov 1971" "Jan 2001" "Mar 2005" "Dec 2007"
(wrongcentury <- as.integer(gsub(".* ", "", out)) > as.integer(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y")))
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
vec[wrongcentury]
# [1] "Nov-60"
zoo::as.yearmon(gsub("-", "-19", vec[wrongcentury]), format = "%b-%Y")
# [1] "Nov 1960"
out[wrongcentury] <- zoo::as.yearmon(gsub("-", "-19", vec[wrongcentury]), format = "%b-%Y")
out
# [1] "Nov 1960" "Nov 1970" "Nov 1971" "Jan 2001" "Mar 2005" "Dec 2007"
```

**Edit**: much more concise recommendation from G. Grothendieck:

```r
out <- zoo::as.yearmon(vec, format="%b-%y")
out - 100 * (out > zoo::as.yearmon(Sys.Date()))
# [1] "Nov 1960" "Nov 1970" "Nov 1971" "Jan 2001" "Mar 2005" "Dec 2007"
```

If your source data ever comes close to 1920, then this inferential solution will further break. (More reason to fix it at the source :-)

Comment: Thanks. But that did not solve my problem with negative outputs. I figured out that when converting earliest_cr_line from string to yearmon, R misinterpreted years which were before 1970. For example, yearmon converted Jan-60 into Nov 2060 instead of Nov 1960. That's what is causing the negative output. Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: or maybe `ym0 <- as.yearmon(vec, "%b-%y"); ym <- ym0 - 100 * (ym0 > as.yearmon(Sys.Date()))`